# вывод данных в таблицу с помощью метода fetch()

Tags: javascript

Начал пробовать учить js. Пытаюсь вывести инфу с файла info.json в таблицу

```js
function GetInfo() {
    fetch('/api/info',{
        //url: "/api/info",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        //contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (info) {
            let rows = "";
            $.each(info, function (index, inf) {
                // добавляем полученные элементы в таблицу
                rows += row(inf);
            });
            $("table tbody").append(rows);
        }
    }).then(response => response.json());
}

window.onload = () =>{
    GetInfo();
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, blog-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Инфо</h2>
    <form name="infoForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="0" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Имя:</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="name" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="content">Содержимое:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="content"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Сохранить</button>
            <a id="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Сбросить</a>
        </div>
    </form>
    <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead><tr><th>Id</th><th>Имя</th><th>Контент</th><th></th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Но неудача, подскажите где ошибаюсь, уже перечитал и перепробовал массу вариантов - безуспешно

Предупреждения в консоле:

```
The key "blog-scalable" is not recognized and ignored.
DevTools filed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighnmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map
DevTools filed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighnmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.postload.js.map
```

Ответ от API: `/api/blogs`

```
[{"name": "dsa", "content": "fsdfs", "id": 1}, {"name": "dsa", "content": "dsa", "id": 2}]
```

Comment: может быть так ? https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/KKpQVqP

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(info, function (index, inf) {
            // добавляем полученные элементы в таблицу
            rows += row(inf);
        });
```

замени на

```
   $.each(info, function (key, value) {
                // добавляем полученные элементы в таблицу
                rows += value;
            });
```

Comment: не помогло, у меня почему-то догадки проблема в response, но все мои попытки также провальны

Comment: success: function (info) { console.log(info) } сделай, и скажи что пишет

Comment: добавил в главный вопрос

Comment: @erleug у тебя же там пусто, значит ты ответ не получил даже, точнее тебе пришел пустой ответ

Comment: я это уже понял, что ничего не возвращает) не пойму как это можно исправить

Comment: @erleug дак что у тебя по пути /api/info делается? какой код там

Comment: содержится файл с инфой info.json c текстом [{"name":"dsa","content":"fsdfs","id":1},{"name":"dsa","content":"dsa","id":2}]

Comment: @erleug бред какой-то)))) ты код покажи, либо у тебя путь кривой и не ведет ни в какой контроллер, тогда просто укажи путь к файлу /path/to/file.json

Comment: @erleug я там в комментарии скинул готовый код на js - он не подходит ?

Comment: @MaximLensky да, ваш код подошел, проблема была все-таки в неправильном заполнении response, спасибо!